# WP7 Memory leak issue in navigation - Listbox binding

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am developing one application in Silverlight for windows phone 7. I am stuck in very common issues which comes in windows phone app however not able to get out of it in any ways. It is memory leak issue which comes during navigation from first page to second, second to first and so on for multiple times.

To solve it, i create one new project having 2 blank pages. Each page has 2 text blocks to print current memory and peak memory and one button to move to next or previous page. When navigate from page 1 to page 2, i make null referance of all 3 things and call gc.collect to destroy the page referance. Same way, while moving from page 2 to page 1, i do the same thing.

I also tried to call gc.collect() in timer for every 500 mili seconds, but still no result. If i remove gc.collect() totally, memory increases in MB so i think it is a must thing.

Here is snippet of my code:

Main Page:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    namespace AppMemory
    {
        public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {

            // Constructor
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                txtCM.Text = "C : " + Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage.ToString();
                txtPM.Text = "P: " + Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage.ToString();
            }

            // Simple button Click event handler to take us to the second page
            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                {
                    this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                }
            }

            protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                {
                    this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                }
            }
            protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                dosposeMemory();
                base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
                this.DataContext = null;
                GC.Collect();
            }

            public void dosposeMemory()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (txtCM != null)
                    {
                        txtCM.Text = null;
                        txtCM = null;
                    }

                    if (txtPM != null)
                    {
                        txtPM.Text = null;
                        txtPM = null;
                    }

                    if (btn1 != null)
                    {
                        btn1.Click -= Button_Click;
                        btn1.Style = null;
                        btn1.Resources.Clear();
                        btn1.Resources = null;
                        btn1 = null;
                    }

                    if (ContentPanel != null)
                    {
                        ContentPanel.Children.Clear();
                        ContentPanel.Resources.Clear();
                        ContentPanel.Resources = null;
                        ContentPanel = null;
                    }

                    if (LayoutRoot != null)
                    {
                        LayoutRoot.DataContext = null;
                        LayoutRoot.Background = null;
                        LayoutRoot.Resources.Clear();
                        LayoutRoot.Resources = null;
                        LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
                        LayoutRoot = null;
                    }

                  if (app1 != null)
                    {
                        app1.Resources.Clear();
                        app1.Resources = null;
                        app1 = null;
                    }

                    GC.Collect();
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {

                }
            }

            ~MainPage()
            {
                System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Second Page:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

    namespace AppMemory
    {
        public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            public Page1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                textBlock1.Text = "C : " + Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage.ToString();
                textBlock2.Text = "P: " + Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage.ToString();
            }
            protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                {
                    this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                }

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                {
                    this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                }
            }
            protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                dosposeMemory();
                base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
                this.DataContext = null;
                GC.Collect();
            }
            public void dosposeMemory()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (textBlock1 != null)
                    {
                        textBlock1.Text = null;
                        textBlock1 = null;
                    }

                    if (textBlock2 != null)
                    {
                        textBlock2.Text = null;
                        textBlock2 = null;
                    }

                    if (ContentPanel != null)
                    {
                        ContentPanel.Children.Clear();
                        ContentPanel.Resources.Clear();
                        ContentPanel.Resources = null;

                        ContentPanel = null;
                    }
                    if (LayoutRoot != null)
                    {
                        LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
                        LayoutRoot.Resources.Clear();
                        LayoutRoot.Resources = null;

                        LayoutRoot = null;
                    }
                    if (page1 != null)
                    {
                        page1.Resources.Clear();
                        page1.Resources = null;
                        page1 = null;
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is tracking of Current Memory which is increasing in each try:

```
    Try Page 1      Page 2
    1   7426048         7442432
    2   6959104     8257536
    3   6934528     8454144
    4   8622080     8458240
    5   8626176     8470528
    6   8630272     8470528
```

Questions:
1) Is my flow and method proper for navigation from and back to manage memory?
2) Is my method to make referance null for text block and button is proper?
3) Also in my actual project, i am using databinding in listbox which i have destrcuted in following way.

```
    if (listCountry != null)
    {
        listCountry.SelectionChanged -= listCountry_SelectionChanged;
        //listCountry.Items.Clear();
        listCountry.DataContext = null;
        listCountry.ItemsSource = null;
        listCountry.Resources.Clear();
        listCountry.Resources = null;
        listCountry = null;
    }
```

I have doubt in this since in my project, there are multiple usage of such listbox.

Please take me out of this since i have spent lots of time in research and updates but not got the solution for current and peak memory.

Thanks in advance.
David Jacobs.

Comment: Please, add link to the sample, so anybody can repro on it's own PC

Comment: Alex, this is demo project on my pc. I have put both the pages' code.

Comment: This leak might be normal behavior of navigation service on WP7. 
To check this out, reproduce scenario with navigation from p1 -> p2 -> p1 and then back to p2 and then back to p1

Comment: and this is awkward
listCountry.Resources.Clear();
listCountry.Resources = null;

Comment: Hi alex.. yeah i thought that. I am not clear about destructing the listbox with data binding. Can you please guide me for this?

Comment: You don't need to destruct elements after you leave page. Only if you really face memory leak.

Comment: Yeah, Alex I am really facing it and need to make sure that my peak memory goes down 70 MB. Can you please send me some demo app with best memory optimization you know for all images, sound, variable, list and other event handlers. I have put all but am doubtful that i have followed correct way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13409/discussion-between-david-jacob-and-alex-sorokoletov)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while developing WP8 app. When you override the `OnBackKeyPress` method, on your second page to be precise, you need to remove the page from stack (or `JournalEntry`) because, if not done so, you leave it on the stack and it cannot be picked up by GC. You need to add `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` to the `OnBackKeyPress` method and it is important first to call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` and then do what you want.